# C# Storing a datatable inside a datatable and then accessing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to create a parent DataTable which holds a series of child DataTables that I can then access by referencing this parent Datatable. I tried to add a Row  containing the child DataTable to this parent Datatable but when I try to access it later all I have access to is the TableName which isn't very helpful.

Here is how I am storing the child DataTable:

```
    private DataTable AddtChidTotParent(DataTable dtChild, DataTable dt, int index)
{

    DataTable temp = dtChild;
    temp.TableName = "Child" + index.ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(index, temp);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    return dt;
}
```

How can I access the actual child DataTable instead of just the TableName?

[Here is a diagram of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOHbY.png)

Comment: A DataSet can hold multiple DataTables. A DataTable obviously can't. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Do you know why you wrote this line? Are you about to explain what you thought it would do? `DataTable temp = dtChild;`

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett Yeah this line is uneccessary.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Now let's get back to my first question.

Comment: Also @ Ed Plunkett when I did some research I did see that DataSets did accomplish this exact scenario but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with just DataTables because I have never used DataSets before. Basically I am trying to add rows to a gridview which is databound to a table in my database but I don't want to alter the actual table in my database, just the gridview. This will be used to provide an estimate to the user using the newly added row and the information already in the DB.

Comment: It might be time to start using DataSets. But it's *really* time to answer the nice man's question and explain why you though this was necessary.

Comment: If you have some kind of relationship between the two tables then consider to look at the class [DataRelation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to express this relationship and use it for records retrieval while you can still have the two tables separate

Comment: @TeeseCaprice Are you saying that you want to display a *concatenation* of the two DataTables?

Comment: @ Steve really the Parent DataTable would act as an array of DataTables which I could access at a later time. So maybe the relation is just the row ID equates to a certain datatable in my DataSet.

Comment: Never allow a lack of experience with a programming structure or concept send you on a wild goose chase to substitute it with a mess of things you already know taped together with hope and stubbornness.  Not only does it lead to bad programming habits and difficult-to-maintain code, but it puts you behind the rest of your own job market and wastes your time.  We've all done it, and shortly after discovered why we should have known better.

Comment: I'm off to get @CDove's comment tattooed on my forearm. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett no I just want to be able to access any one of the child DataTables so I can add a row  and then bind the appropriate gridview to it.

Comment: Is there any reason at all why `Dictionary<String, DataTable>` wouldn't do the job? What you need to do is write up a clear statement, in plain English, of what your *goal* is, without reference to any of your thoughts about how to achieve it. You're dribbling out hints but I'm sure there's a lot you haven't told us.

Comment: @CDove Word lol I am 2 months into my first webdev job but I hear you man, I was told by a co worker / peer who is like a year new that a dataset would be unnecessary so I started huntin goose, Thanks guys I will try datsets

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok, I will try to explain to the best of  my ability. I have three gridviews. The first contains a list of parts that the user might want to add to a project. The second gridview contains a list subgridviews which display parts that are already in the project. The third is what I am struggling with currently and that is I want to be able to pick a part from gridview one and add it to one of the subgridviews in gridview 2 and display in a subgridview in gridview 3. I am using datatables because all of the subgridviews are databound but I don not want to affect the database.

Comment: Thanks. What is a "list of subgridviews", just a list of datagrids? Why are the selected parts in multiple datagrids instead of one big datagrid? I think a screenshot would be a big help. If the third gridview isn't finished maybe you could sketch it in with mspaint or something

Comment: Thank you @EdPlunkett I got it to work by using the DataSet method, and adding tables and accessing them that way much easier than I thought it would be.